# Why are there redlines for my html code in regard to break tag and comment tag?

Tags: html

hi guys this is my first time posting a question in StackOverflow, trying out the user interface for StackOverflow, hope you guys can enlighten me about my question.

with regards,
student from Singapore

[image: Screenshot of my code]

Comment: go over it with your mouse, does it show something?

Comment: I voted to close this question because the cause is a simple error in the code.  See my answer

Comment: `<input>` requires a closing tag .

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, the lines are highighted in red due to the fact that there are synatical errors in your HTML.

Look at the first one:

```
<input type="range"min="0"max="50"value="20"



<br>
```

The `<br>` has an error because the preceeding `input` element has not been closed correctly.  Add a `>` to the end of the element and the error will disappear.

The same is true of your second error:

```
<input type="date"min="01-01-1996"max="31-12-2020"



<!--why is there a red line-->
```

When examining highlighted errors, a cursory glance through the preceeding lines of code can often reveal the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close your `input` tags you can close the input tag by adding `>` at the end of the `input` tag
Replace your `input` tags with these:

`input type="range" min="0" max="50" value="20">`

`input type="date" min="01-01-1966" max="31-12-2020">`